# Did Allah bring back to life a man and a boy who were burning each other after death?

Tags: prophet-isa, homosexuality, akhirah

In Major Sins by [Al-Dhahabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Dhahabi) ([pdf](http://www.islamtomorrow.com/books/major_sins/majorSins.pdf)):

> It was related that Jesus, the son of Mary (pbuh), passed by a flaming fire burning a man when he was in a journey. Then, Jesus carried some water to extinguish the fire. But, the fire turned into a boy and the man turned into fire. Surprisingly, Jesus said, "O Lord! May You return them back to life to ask them how they are? Allah then brought them to life. They were a man and a boy. Jesus asked them, "Who are you?" The man said, "O spirit of Allah, in the world I was afflicted by loving this boy and out of sexual excitement, I sodomized him. Later on when we died, we alternatively burned one another. This is our torture until the Day of Judgement."

I was surprised to read this as I don't recall reading anything else like it previously.  I'm wondering if it's correct.

**Question**: Did Allah bring back to life a man and a boy who were burning each other after death?

The .pdf translation does not have a reference.  Essentially, I'm asking for a reference for this (Qur'an, hadith, etc.).  Where did this story come from?  (Google keeps leading me back to Major Sins.)

Comment: this story was mentioned in a book of of ibn-hajar alhaithamy , it's a book about Major sins too ! [alzwajr](http://www.islamicbook.ws/amma/alzwajr-.pdf)

Comment: i don't know if this is accepted ! but this website could help .i always  search about authenticity of ahadith in the arabic version of  [multaqa ahl alhadeth](http://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vbe/forumdisplay.php?f=18&order=desc&page=7)

Comment: this could be some vision Jesus- pbuh- have gone through. as some people do. You can find some instances in http://www.spiritual-experiences.com/. I mean it need not be that the man and the boy were raised alive a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This story is mentioned in an older version printed (not revised) and has a note from the revisor of the book (Mohyi Addin Misto) that it is not the real version from Imam Althahabi.

The revised version does not have this story and many other stories that do not have authentic sources, which does not match the style of Imam AlThahabi as he is known for his capability of differentiating the authentic from others.

I cannot at the moment search for English sources to prove what I mentioned but I will provide the Arabic ones anyway.

This is an [Arabic article](http://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=241130) explains the point I mentioned that this version is not by Imam Althahabi.

And this is a [scan of the revised version](https://archive.org/stream/alkbaerzhms#page/n207/mode/2up) of the book it does not have this story.(page 201-208)

A [second print](https://archive.org/details/waq93403) does not have the story

So the answer is this story is not in Quran or Sunnah.